# Specifying with changed pom.xml name

Tags: maven

Is there a way to specify a renamed child pom.xml in the parent pom.xml?

```
.
 |-- my-module
 | `-- child_pom.xml
 | `-- pom.xml
 `-- parent_pom.xml
 `-- pom.xml
```

set parent_pom:

```
<groupId>com.multi.module</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packagin>    

<modules>
  <module>my-module</module>
</modules>
```

set child_pom:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.multi.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <relativePath>../parent_pom.xml</relativePath>    
</parent>

<artifactId>child</artifactId>
```

When running 'mvn -f parent_pom.xml package', the pom is read, not the child_pom.
Is there a way to make Maven have parent_pom read child_pom in the above structure?

Comment: Why do you need that? Convention over configuration paradigm...

Comment: I am creating a program using Eclipse RCP.
I am now planning to change the existing build process using ant to maven.

These are the modules I use. configuration, core, ui, app, plugin, command.

Here, configuration, core, ui, app, and plugin are needed to create window, linux, and mac programs.
The build settings are set in pom.xml.

And the console version requires configuration, core, and command.
I want to set this build settings in parent.xml.

Is this completely the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Is this really impossible?
Even if I try to find documents related to this problem, I can't find them.

Comment: Using Maven Tychon and defining the deps via pom/manifest..

Comment: There seems to be no way to find and build child_pom by running parent_pom...
Thank you for your interest in my problems.

Comment: Usually you can build from the root via `mvn package` ... that will use all the children given via modules... can you show an example project on github or alike?

Comment: This is my project.
https://github.com/Srltas/cubrid-migration/tree/maven_update